# Cohomology of Hawaiian earring?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Do the infinite wedge of circles and the Hawaiian earring have the same cohomology? I am happy that they have different homologies (the first is countably generated, the second uncountably).

Comment: I doubt it, because I don't think $$\text{Hom}\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb Z, \mathbb Z\right)$$ is even $2^{\aleph_0}$-generated.

Comment: It may seem counterintuitive, but Specker's theorem says that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ is a free abelian group on countably many generators: $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$. A nice write-up can be found [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10239/is-it-true-that-as-bbb-z-modules-the-polynomial-ring-and-the-power-series-r).

Answer (score 3):

No. Let $E$ denote the Hawaiian earring. Then the first cohomology groups are respectively $$H^1(E;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z},$$ as explained [here](https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/the-hawaiian-earring-group-is-not-free-part-ii/), and $$H^1(\bigvee_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S^1;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} H^1(S^1;\mathbb{Z}) \cong \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}.$$